# Questions on main pages are very spread out vertically; is that intentional?

Tags: discussion, design

There seems to be a lot more spacing between questions on the main pages (main and meta) than on some other sites ([Mi Yodeya](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/), [EL&U](https://english.stackexchange.com/), and [MSO](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/) for example).  At my current window size and zoom level, I'm seeing 5 questions here on Workplace Meta but 7-8 on the others.  It looks like most of the extra space is between the top of the title text and the separator bar above it.

Screenshots taken in a default browser configuration (no add-ons) while not logged in:

[image: The Workplace]

For comparison:

[image: EL&U]

The screen shots are from Chrome (23.0.1271.95) on XP.  I see the same behavior in Firefox on XP (18.0.1) and OS 10.6 (27.0.1).

Comment: I didn't tag "bug" because this might be by design -- that's my question.  If it's not by design then please consider this a bug report.

Comment: Reminds me a bit of a couple other sites, so maybe intentional?

Comment: Workaround for the image issue: upload via another SE site and copy the URL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The spacing between the questions is intentional. We want a relaxed feel, so white space helps a lot accomplishing this.

Comment: Maybe its just me, but the excessive whitespace bothers me a lot and speaks to me of unprofessionalism (since I am a UI developer, and am used to new developers not caring about whitespace and often leaving extra whitespace everywhere)